# Creating a form with multiple posibilities

Tags: forms, gui-design, best-practice

I'm relatively new here so please forgive me if this question is to open ended.

I am working on a form for the user to enter an event. The catch however, is that there are 4 ways of entering the dates for the event:

1.) Start date + interval(daily,weekly,...) + repetitions(1,2,3,...)

2.) End date  + interval + repetitions

3.) Start date + end date + interval

4.) A set of fixed dates.

See screenshot:
[image: The current form]

Each possibility has different required fields. Currently i display all the possibilities in the form. However, I was wondering if there is any better way of designing such forms. Anyhelp/ideas/guids are very much appreciated

Thanks,

Benedict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take this tried and true solution from Outlook as a starting point, and tweak it to my needs.

[image]

Alternatively, the one from Google Calendar is also a good option, although I think it's not as robust and clear as the Outlook one.

[image]

Comment: Thank, I thing the Outlook version is exactly what I am looking for.